# Ambiguity in trace of curvature 2-form matrix

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, characteristic-classes

My question is about computing the first Chern class from the trace of curvature 2-form matrix via the Chern–Weil theory. First Chern class is given by
$$ c_{1}=\left[{\frac {i}{2\pi }}\operatorname {tr} \Omega \right]   ...(1)$$
where the curvature 2-form matrix is defined as
$ \Omega =d\omega +{\frac {1}{2}}[\omega ,\omega ] \, \ $ or $ \, \ ⁢{\Omega^a}_b  = d⁢{\omega^a}_b + {\omega^a}_i \wedge  {\omega^i}_b  \, \ ... \ (2) $.

It is obvious that the trace of a real 2-form valued matrix $\Omega$ is always zero. So, I'm confused when trying to compute the first Chern class from the trace of curvature 2-form matrix. $ \mathbb{CP}^1$ case is simple since we only have one component of $\Omega$ and trace is simply the Kähler 2-form.

For example, I have computed $\Omega$ matrix by using equation (2) for $ \mathbb{CP}^2$. Trace of $\Omega$ matrix is zero as expected. But we know that $ c_1(\mathbb{CP}^2)$ is not zero. I know that there is another way to compute first Chern class of $ \mathbb{CP}^2$ which includes cohomology groups etc. but I need to specifically solve/understand this trace issue.

I am using real coordinates such as $r, \phi, \theta $ and $ \psi$ for explicit calculations. It is possible to write the Fubini-Study metric by using 2 complex coordinates but I couldn't figure out how to compute the complexified $\Omega$ and how to implement it in computing the first Chern class.

Comment: $\Omega$ here is a skew-hermitian $2$-form, which means each diagonal element and therefore the trace is $i$ times a real $2$-form.

Comment: Thanks, @Deane. I guess you meant $\Omega$ is a skew-Hermitian matrix with entries of complex 2-forms. So, that means one should use complex charts for computing the $\Omega$ in equation (1). But I couldn't find explicit examples for that computation. 
I can write the Fubini-Study metric with complex coordinates but I am missing the details of getting the correct skew-Hermitian matrix $\Omega$. My guess is to use the complex Riemann tensor as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%E2%80%93Study_metric#Connection_and_curvature 

Can you give any reference or elaborate more on this problem?

Comment: Not sure what you can by "complex $2$-forms". A complex $2$-form is the same as a real $2$-form, except that the coefficients are complex. For example, $$ dz^j\wedge dz^k= (dx^j+idy^j)\wedge(dx^k+idy^k) = dx^j\wedge dx^k - dy^j\wedge dy^k + i(dx^j\wedge dy^k - dx^k\wedge dy^j). $$ However, it is indeed usually easier to work with the coordinates $(z^1, \dots, z^n)$ than the $x$ and $y$ coordinates. You should look at a textbook on complex differential geometry. A classic one is Griffiths and Harris. Another old one is Wells' Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds.